# Two representations of $\text{M}_n(k)$ of same dimension over $k$ isomorphic or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Is it true or not that any two representations of the algebra $\text{M}_n(k)$ of the same (finite) dimension over $k$ are isomorphic?

Comment: What do you know about representations of $M_n(k)$?

Comment: Five upvotes for an easy problem statement question is charitable, to say the least. The user should easily be able to supply context, here!